# Getting Styles for Scraped HTML (XCode Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am creating an application to scrape the body tags of a URL and display it in a UIWebView.

So far I have got a url of which the user inputs,
Scraped it for just the content between the  tags,
made it show in a UIWebView.

The problem Im getting is that when loading this modified html string the Styles are not present. Inline styles such as italics and images are being shown but fonts and colour are not.

I have tried using numerous methods such as NSBundles to try and grab the URL directory to access the CSS file and setting the baseURL of the Webview to the URL (This would get the unedited HTML right?)

Im using this page as an example http://ehko.co.uk/new-year-new-website

Any help would be appreciated, Been scratching my head on this for days

EDIT: Here is some of my code

```
[self.wvMain loadHTMLString:webData baseURL:origRequest];
```

webData holds the string of html starting  and ends 
origRequest is the Original NSURL object I use to get the original HTML before editing.
wvMain is my WebView

```
self.request = [NSURL URLWithString:input];
```

^ This is the Original URL Request

Comment: Can we see the troubled code?

Comment: I have now added what I think might help. although im unsure